# How to mask certain variables in a row of a Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, mask, data-manipulation

I have a large `data frame` and I am interested in filtering the dataset based on a certain condition. Only 1 row follows the condition. I would like to turn 8 variables of this row to `NAN`, I am not doing the right thing.

Here is the idea

```py
# filter the dataset 
error_in_the_data = df_frame.start == "embed"
df_frame.loc[error_in_the_data,"Info_1":"Info_8"]
```

How do I mask this variables in that row that fufil the condition of `error_in_the_data` to `NAN`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, only assign `np.nan` for filter by mask and by columns names:

```
df_frame.loc[error_in_the_data,"Info_1":"Info_8"] = np.nan
```

Comment: Great! Thank you so much!